# Cannot remove the white space on the bottom of the page (mobile)

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am having a problem with the background image on my body tag. There is a white space on the bottom of the page when viewed on mobile.

[image: remove white space]

Here is my css code:

```
     body { 
  background:  url("/images/laptop_bg.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Georgia, sans-serif;
 }

html{
  height: 100%;
}
```

The solutions I found on stack-overflow does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you try to set body's height to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Set `height: 100vh;` to `html` **AND TRY**  `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
     body { 
  background:  url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

html{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I tried tried that earlier and it still does not work. i fixed it by removing the css code on the `html` tag. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

For your `body` tag, set the **CSS** as follows for a full display of the `background-image`.

```
body {

width: 100%;
background-image: url("/images/laptop_bg.jpg");
background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
background-size: auto, cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Georgia, sans-serif;

}
```